# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_shipping_packages()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to get the current shipping zone of the user but I am getting an error every time I am trying to get it

```
// The package. 

// Get cart shipping packages
$shipping_packages = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_packages();

// Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
$shipping_zone = $woocommerce->wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );

$zone_id   = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
$zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name

// Testing output
echo '<p>Zone id: ' . $zone_id . ' | Zone name: ' . $zone_name . '</p>';
```

Error info

[image: Error info]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- `$woocommerce` global variable is not defined *(and it's can be replaced by `WC()`)*,
- `wc_get_shipping_zone()` is not a Woocommerce method but a function.

Try the following instead *(for plugins see below)*:

```
// Get cart shipping packages
$shipping_packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

// Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
$shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );

$zone_id       = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
$zone_name     = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name

// Testing output
echo '<p>Zone id: ' . $zone_id . ' | Zone name: ' . $zone_name . '</p>';
```

It should work

---

For plugins, try

```
global $woocommerce;

// Get cart shipping packages
$shipping_packages = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_packages();

// Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
$shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );

$zone_id       = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
$zone_name     = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name
```

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 134 of file wp-content/plugins/risk-free-cash-on-delivery-cod-woocommerce/risk_free_advanced_cod.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function WC() in wp-content/plugins/risk-free-cash-on-delivery-cod-woocommerce/risk_free_advanced_cod.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 wp-settings.php(388): include_once()
...

Comment: @Md.SafiqulIslam I have updated my answer… This seems to be an issue on an outdated plugin…

Comment: Both of them are throwing errors. I also tried to downgrade the woo-commerce plugin . What should I check to fix the problem

Comment: @Md.SafiqulIslam The problem seems to come from `risk-free-cash-on-delivery-cod-woocommerce` plugin that can't access Woocommerce global variable… It should load after woocommerce, checking that woocommerce is loaded before. Don't downngrade WooCommerce.